# ViewModel Live Data observers calling on rotation

Tags: android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In my view model, I have two properties:

```
private val databaseDao = QuestionDatabase.getDatabase(context).questionDao()
val allQuestions: LiveData<List<Question>> = databaseDao.getAllQuestions()
```

I have observers set on "allQuestions" in my fragment and I'm noticing the observer is being called when I rotate the device. Even though the View Model is only being created once (can tell via a log statement in init()), the observer methods are still being called.

Why is this? I would think the point is to have persistency in the View Model. Ideally, I want the database questions to be only loaded once, regardless of rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `LiveData` is lifecycle aware.
And When you rotate the screen you UI Controller [Activity/Fragment] goes through various lifecycle states and lifecycle callbacks.
And since `LiveData` is lifecycle aware, it updates the detail accordingly.

I have tried to explain this with following points:

1. When the UI Controller is offscreen, `Live Data` performs no updates.
2. When the UI Controller is back on screen, it gets current data.
   *(Because of this property you are getting above behavior)*
3. When UI controller is destroyed, it performs cleanup on its own.
4. When **new** UI Controller starts observing live data, it gets current data.

Answer (score 0):

add this check inside observer

if(lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED){

//code

}

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, after reading the jetpack guideline doc, I solve it. Just like what @SVK mentioned, after the rotation of the screen, activity/fragment were re-created.
Base on the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64062616,

```
class SingleLiveEvent<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

val TAG: String = "SingleLiveEvent"

private val mPending = AtomicBoolean(false)

@MainThread
override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {

    if (hasActiveObservers()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
    }

    // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
    super.observe(owner, Observer<T> { t ->
        if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
        }
    })
}

override fun observeForever(observer: Observer<in T>) {
    if (hasActiveObservers()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
    }

    // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
    super.observeForever { t ->
        if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
        }
    }
}

@MainThread
override fun setValue(@Nullable t: T?) {
    mPending.set(true)
    super.setValue(t)
}

/**
 * Used for cases where T is Void, to make calls cleaner.
 */
@MainThread
fun call() {
    value = null
}
```